# How to extract samples from a Tensorflow Dataset which have the same label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to generate batched samples from a TF Dataset in the following manner: each batch would consist of two samples with have the same 'label' feature. What is the most efficient way to achieve this in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have some kind of data with multiple labels like this:

```py
x = tf.random.uniform((10, 2), maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.random.uniform((10, ), maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
```

In order to achieve your goal. "each batch would consist of two samples with have the same 'label' feature" you could use the `filter` function to create separate datasets for each label and then the `concatenate` function of the `tf.data.Dataset` API to merge these datasets into one:

```py
x = tf.random.uniform((10, 2), maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.random.uniform((10, ), maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

batch_size = 2
dataset0 = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.equal(y, 0)).batch(batch_size)
dataset1 = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.equal(y, 1)).batch(batch_size)
dataset2 = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.equal(y, 2)).batch(batch_size)
dataset3 = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.equal(y, 3)).batch(batch_size)

dataset = dataset0.concatenate(dataset1).concatenate(dataset2).concatenate(dataset3).shuffle(buffer_size=20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I had in mind too. Wondering if there was anything more efficient as this might require a shuffling step after the concatenate.

Comment: Does shuffling slow down your code ? I can’t imagine that it is so inefficient.

Comment: Actually it is only a nominal slowdown at the beginning of my training pipeline so it wasn't too much of a hindrance.